# highlight indentation with emacs client

Tags: faces, highlighting, server

I realized that neither highlight-indentation nor highlight-indent-guides works with emacs in server/client mode.

I'm launching emacs server/client like this :

```
$ /usr/bin/emacs --daemon
$ emacsclient -c
```

I'm launching emacs standalone like this :

```
$ emacs
```

I can see that the faces are different and highlighting indentation won't be displayed with emacs client.

The screenshot shows client mode on the left and standalone mode on the right. I disabled every customization to debug.
[image]

I use emacs 26.1

Is there a bug to track down ? Do I miss a setup ?

Comment: You didn't post your config or what exact libraries you tried and how you configured them.

[highlight-indent-guides](https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides) works even
when started in daemon mode (I use it daily).
Maybe you switched themes (/or opened first frame) after loading the lib?
If so try calling `M-x highlight-indent-guides-auto-set-faces`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Strangely enough, restarting my emacs daemon later, the problem was fixed. I can't tell why.